# Robot Framework - Visitor Interface - How do I get keyword children of keywords?

Tags: python, robotframework, visitor-pattern

After implementing Robot's [SuiteVisitor Interface](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.model.html#robot.model.visitor.SuiteVisitor) the functions `def start_suite(self, suite)`, `def start_test(self, test)` and `def start_keyword(self, keyword)` are being called as expected. But when I try to list the keyword children of keywords, I get empty lists:

```
def start_suite(self, suite):
    logger.console("Event Start Suite: {}".format(suite.name))
    for x in suite.tests:
        logger.console("-> Test Name: {}".format(x))
        for y in x.keywords:
            logger.console("---> Keyword: {}".format(y))
            for z in y.keywords:
                logger.console("-----> Child Keyword: {}".format(z))

def start_test(self, test):
    logger.console("Event Start Test {}".format(test.name))
    for x in test.keywords:
        logger.console("---> Keyword: {}".format(x))
        for z in x.keywords:
            logger.console("-----> Child Keyword: {}".format(z))    

def start_keyword(self, keyword):
    logger.console("Event Start Keyword {}".format(keyword.name))
    for x in keyword.keywords:
        logger.console("-----> Child Keyword: {}".format(x))
```

Can someone explain why?

I register the visitor via the listener:

```
def start_suite(self, data, result):
    logger.console("Listener Start Suite")
    visitor = Visitor()
    data.visit(visitor)
```

Is there more information needed from my side to be able to answer this question?

Comment: Can you create complete examples. Currently there is some code missing (perhaps for brevity reasons) but it makes it more time consuming to recreate your situation. Having full classes for the visitor, listener and the command line argument you use to start are key for me. A short robot example would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following setup the custom Suite Visitor logs the keywords defined in the test case. The main difference is that the below example adds the class as a prerunmodifier: `--prerunmodifier SoVisitor.SoVisitor`.

**SoVisitor.robot**

```
*** Test Cases ***
TC 1
    Custom Keyword
    Another Keyword

TC 2
    Custom Keyword
    Another Keyword


*** Keywords ***
Custom Keyword
    Sub Keyword
    No Operation

Another Keyword
    No Operation 

Sub Keyword
    No Operation 
    enter code here
```

**SoVisitor.py**

```
from robot.model.visitor import SuiteVisitor
from robot.api import logger

class SoVisitor(SuiteVisitor):
    def start_suite(self, suite):
        logger.console("Event Start Suite: {}".format(suite.name))
        for x in suite.tests:
            logger.console("-> Test Name: {}".format(x))
            for y in x.keywords:
                logger.console("---> Keyword: {}".format(y))
                for z in y.keywords:
                    logger.console("-----> Child Keyword: {}".format(z))

    def start_test(self, test):
        logger.console("Event Start Test {}".format(test.name))
        for x in test.keywords:
            logger.console("---> Keyword: {}".format(x))
            for z in x.keywords:
                logger.console("-----> Child Keyword: {}".format(z))    

    def start_keyword(self, keyword):
        logger.console("Event Start Keyword {}".format(keyword.name))
        for x in keyword.keywords:
            logger.console("-----> Child Keyword: {}".format(x))
```

The RED editor then generates the following command and console output:

```
Command: C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27\python.exe -m robot.run --listener C:\Users\anne\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir4913575656218095666\TestRunnerAgent.py:55023 -s RobotVisitor.SoVistor --prerunmodifier SoVisitor.SoVisitor C:\Users\anne\eclipse-workspace\RobotVisitor
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0.4 (Python 2.7.15 on win32)
Event Start Suite: RobotVisitor
Event Start Suite: SoVistor
-> Test Name: TC 1
---> Keyword: Custom Keyword
---> Keyword: Another Keyword
-> Test Name: TC 2
---> Keyword: Custom Keyword
---> Keyword: Another Keyword
Event Start Test TC 1
---> Keyword: Custom Keyword
---> Keyword: Another Keyword
Event Start Keyword Custom Keyword
Event Start Keyword Another Keyword
Event Start Test TC 2
---> Keyword: Custom Keyword
---> Keyword: Another Keyword
Event Start Keyword Custom Keyword
Event Start Keyword Another Keyword
==============================================================================
RobotVisitor                                                                  
==============================================================================
RobotVisitor.SoVistor                                                         
==============================================================================
TC 1                                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TC 2                                                                  | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RobotVisitor.SoVistor                                                 | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
RobotVisitor                                                          | PASS |
2 critical tests, 2 passed, 0 failed
2 tests total, 2 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\anne\eclipse-workspace\RobotVisitor\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\anne\eclipse-workspace\RobotVisitor\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\anne\eclipse-workspace\RobotVisitor\report.html
```

Comment: This is the exact same behaviour, like in my case. ""-----> Child Keyword: Sub Keyword" is never printed, although I would expect to get access to the list of sub keywords as well. Am I expecting the wrong thing?