# Robot Framework - Get Suite paths without executing

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to start and kill a Mock Database for each individual testsuite in my executed tests within a jenkins pipeline. Therefore I would like to get a list of all the testsuite paths that would be executed, given all of the include, exclude tags and other modifiers.

e.g. when i start

```
python some.script.py -e DRAFT -i CORE path/to/testsuites
```

I'd like to get a list of all the paths to the testsuites.

I've tried using a prerunmodifier with [Suitevisitor](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/autodoc/robot.model.html#robot.model.visitor.SuiteVisitor) (similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554210/robot-framework-visitor-interface-how-do-i-get-keyword-children-of-keywords)) but that doesn't stop the tests from executing afterwards.
example with prerunmodifier:

```
python -m robot -e DRAFT -i CORE --prerunmodifier path.to.SuiteVisitor.Script path/to/testsuites
```

Comment: Why not do it in suite setup and teardown?

Comment: Because atm the robot scripts are executed within a docker container, whereas the mock database runs on the jenkins server itself. A different approach would be to have the db in another container but accessing a different container/jenkins itself from within robot could get tricky.

Comment: It can be still done if you can access the DB even though you are running it in Jenkins.

Comment: Trying this out now.

Comment: If you don't want the tests to run, have you considered using the --dryrun feature of robot along with the --prerunmodifier option?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes I considered it but was looking for a cleaner way. Currently trying out to do it via Setup from witihn RF. If that turns out to be a dead end, I will probably do it with dryrun.